# Cloud functions to schedule Dataflow effectively?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

What are some best options to schedule Dataflow job using Cloud functions?
I would want to schedule the dataflow job to start and stop at some time.

The dataflow job might be reading from an unbounded source and might run continuously, so looking to have it scheduled to stop.

Answer (score 0):

Since Google Cloud Functions enable you to write functions to respond to events in your cloud environment, regarding to stop Dataflow jobs [I would use a cron job](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron).

It will just send a request to a defined URL in your app which calling the API can do whatever you consider.

```
cron:
- description: "start dataflow job"
  url: /tasks/summary
  schedule: every 24 hours
- description: "stop dataflowjob"
  url: /tasks/stop
  schedule: every day 20:00
  timezone: Australia/NSW
- description: "monday morning summary"
  url: /mail/weekly
  schedule: every monday 09:00
  timezone: Australia/NSW
```

You would need anyway to do a HTTP request in order to trigger the Cloud Function.

Comment: Is there an option to call the Dataflow template directly from the Cron? Also, I see the option to stop dataflow job is only through gcloud command or through console right now, so does that mean are you suggesting to have an API to call the gcloud to stop the dataflow job, and then have the API scheduled through Cron? It doesn't look straight forward to me. Instead of which, I see using a regular Cron scheduler to directly call the gcloud cancel.

Comment: The documentation suggests that Dataflow jobs can only be **started** in this way, as they can be started with [an API request](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/executing-templates#using-the-rest-api)- however stopping the job needs to be done either through the console or the command line. 

For your particular case, it seems that a regular Cron scheduler would be best to call the [gcloud dataflow jobs cancel](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/cancel) command.